# Bootstrap grid layout not shown properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Actually i'm trying to build a page by using bootstrap grid system but the content is not going to be set as i would it to be.

Actually i would have 1 column with datapicker 1 column with 2 rows, one with 3 dought charts and one belowe with bar chart.

The issue is that the column with charts instead of going at right of datapicker column is going down of it.

Here is how it look's like

[image]

And how i would that to be

[image]

Here is the code of that grid

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <div class="card text-center card-date">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="datepicker"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                            <canvas id="barchart1"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                            <canvas id="barchart2"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                            <canvas id="barchart3"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: are you using any custom CSS? & what is all canvas size?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani only the datepicker card has width set to 18rem other canvas autosize to it's parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-top">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card text-center card-date">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div id="datepicker"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                 <canvas id="barchart1"></canvas>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                 <canvas id="barchart2"></canvas>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body text-center">
                 <canvas id="barchart3"></canvas>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `.container` before using `.row`

- Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s
  contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or
  .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device
  sizes.
- Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
  (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This
  padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This 
  way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the
  left side.

Comment: Actually i was yet using .container-fluid, the real problem was the gutter, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm using exactly your code with Bootstrap 4 and i receive the desired result.
Maybe your screen is to small, that it getting displayed below?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <style>
    #datepicker {
      width: 18rem  
    }
</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="card text-center card-date">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="datepicker">date picker</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body text-center">
                              <canvas id="barchart1"></canvas>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body text-center">
                              <canvas id="barchart2"></canvas>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body text-center">
                              <canvas id="barchart3"></canvas>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using grid may depends on your responsive strategy but if i'm make a mistake something like this do the trick.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card text-center card-date">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <canvas id="barchart1"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <canvas id="barchart2"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <canvas id="barchart3"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i've tryed something similar but the result is the following: https://imgur.com/a/8iN1zZ7 if i use col-md-4 in datepicker column there will be some space between two columns while if i use col-auto in datepicker, there will be free space at the right of charts column

Comment: the datepicker card is width 18rem

Comment: It seems it's canvas width issue. you could use flexbox i think.